# Vim в Обычном [Normal] режиме всегда с английской раскладкой клавиатуры

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Система Ubuntu 14.04, Vim 7.4.52.
При редактировании не англоязычных текстов приходится работать с разными раскладками клавиатуры. Например, в системе установлены английская, русская, украинская раскладки.
В Vim редактирование происходит в **Обычном** (англ. Normal) режиме, который включается клавишей <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
Нюанс в том, что если редактировать текст кириллицей (включена русская или украинская, e.t.c. раскладка), то перейдя в **Обычный** режим по клавише <kbd>ESC</kbd> и не меняя раскладку на английскую - ни одна команда не срабатывает.
Раскладку в системе меняю по <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> и хотелось бы эту горячую клавишу не менять.
Поиск дал несколько вариантов решения, в частности назначение другой горячей клавиши (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>) внутри самого Vim не меняя системную раскладку. Как вариант можно пользоваться, но хотелось бы более "универсальное" решение, например при нажатии <kbd>ESC</kbd> запоминать текущую раскладку в режиме вставки и автоматически переключать раскладку на английский. После выполнения команд и возвращения в режим вставки - возвращать сохраненную раскладку.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать чтобы Vim переключал автоматически раскладку на английскую при переходе в **Обычный** режим?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил частично задачу через d-bus

```
function! SetUsLayout()
   silent !qdbus org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Keyboard org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.SetInputSource 0 > /dev/null
endfunction

autocmd InsertLeave * call SetUsLayout()
```

теперь по нажатию ESC и переходе в командный режим клавиатурная раскладка переключается на английскую.
Можно даже команду в функции SetUsLayout записать короче:

```
silent !gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

Осталось решить вопрос с запоминанием той раскладки с которой выходили из режима вставки и установки ее, при возврате в режим вставки.

Comment: пока временно отмечаю, как наиболее верный , именно по моему вопросу, хотя и не полный.

Answer (score 3):

Есть решение, не уверен, удовлетворит ли оно вас полностью, наоборот привязать команды в том числе на русские символы. Попробуйте поместить в .vimrc следующую строку

```
" Русская раскладка
set langmap=ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕHГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ;`qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl\\;'zxcvbnm\\,.~QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\\"ZXCVBNM<>
```

Comment: Впринципе, как вариант - работает. Дело в том, что не уверен , что оно будет работать в 100% случаев набора комманд в другой раскладке. Т.е. когда комманда будет не однобуквенной, а из нескольких букв в разных регистрах (где-то попалась статья, об этом)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста мне! Я в нормальный режим выхожу из режима редактирования двумя нажатиями по клавише ';'(без кавычек), но только с английской раскладкой, а как можно зделать чтоб с русской расскладкой тоже работало?

Answer (score 2):

Используй Vim'овскую раскладку. У меня переключение по <leader>w

```
function! EnRuHighlight()
    if &iminsert == 0
        execute "AirlineTheme light"
        set iminsert=1
    else
        execute "AirlineTheme lucius"
        set iminsert=0
    endif
endfunction

" Настраиваем переключение раскладок клавиатуры по <C-^>
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin

" Раскладка по умолчанию - английская
set iminsert=0

" аналогично для строки поиска и ввода команд
set imsearch=0

" {{{ swith language En-Ru
nmap <leader>w <ESC>:call EnRuHighlight()<CR>
imap <leader>w <ESC>:call EnRuHighlight()<CR>a
" }}}
```

Comment: Гугление дало несколько вариантов решения, в частности назначение другого хоткея (Ctrl+^) внутри самого Vim не меняя системную раскладку. Как вариант можно пользоваться, но хотелось бы более "универсальное" решение, например при нажатии ESC запоминать текущую расскладку в режиме вставки и автоматически переключать расскладку на английский. После выполнения комманд и возвращения в режим вставки - возвращать сохраненную раскладку.
Вопрос: можно ли сделать чтобы Vim переключал автоматически раскладку на английскую при переходе в коммандный режим?

Comment: @uralbash Конечно, пусть теперь у каждой софтины своя комбинация будет