# Emacs. Можно ли переназначить "без последствий" часть клавиатурных сокращений?

Tags: vim, emacs, hotkeys

Можно ли в Emacs переназначить часть операций с текстом/файлами под более привычные(удобные) для себя комбинации клавиш, без конфликтов с другими командами? Или стоит изучить те которые по умолчанию? Пробовал Vim, но там ІМНО не стоит изменять хоткеи по умолчанию, да и там все довольно логично,да и много команд реализуются одной клавишей, так что не увидел особой необходимости в замене.

Comment: Конечно, можно. Только смотрите (через C-h k) чего лишаетесь (или переназначьте это в свою очередь).

Comment: Как-то так я себе это и представлял.   @avp,  а можно узнать лично ваше мнение, стоит ли вообще начинать переназначения?

Comment: Я на F1-F12 по привычке вешаю некоторые команды, а вообще, если не привыкли, то наверное не стоит, а то всюду придется свой .emacs таскать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандартные сочетания архаичны и загадочны, существует несколько подходов в основе. Хорошие примеры: [Evil Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) (vim-аддиктам),  [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs), [Ergo Emacs](http://ergoemacs.org/), [Boon](https://github.com/jyp/boon), [fingers](https://github.com/fgeller/fingers.el).

Технической проблемы тут нет, это вопрос эргономики и управления сложностью конфигурации.

Вот из Vim на EMACS можно перейти только благодаря Evil-mode, ценой громоздкого конфига, однако с [божьей помощью](https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode) можно отказаться от Evil-mode, сохранив при том модальность. К вопросу, `HJKL` по-умолчанию в EMACS выполняют несущественные функции (С-h дублируется ), следовательно, такое можно и перемапить.  `FBNP`-навигацию же, естественную для EMACS, и `C-x-...` `M-x-...`, `C-c-...`, повсеместно используемое - проще оставить нетронутым:

```
(use-package god-mode

  :bind ( ( "M-i" . god-local-mode )
          ( "<escape>" . god-local-mode )
          ( "C-j" . next-line )
          ( "C-k" . previous-line )
          ( "C-h" . backward-char )
          ( "C-l" . forward-char )
          ( "C-d C-f" . delete-forward-char )
          ( "C-d C-b" . backward-delete-char-untabify )
          ( "C-d C-e" . kill-line )
          ( "C-d C-w" . delete-trailing-whitespace )
          ( "C-d C-a" . delete-to-begin ) ) )
```

В стиле Vi, одну клавишу можно использовать для целого ряда действий. Например, удаление строки `dd`, до конца строки: `de`,  до начала строки: `da`,  вперёд: `df`, назад: `db` etc. См. также Hydras.

Хороший стиль - повторные нажатия одной клавиши + модификатор: `v` - *старт выделения слова*, повторное `v` - [expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) (увеличить выделение), `M-v` - *contract-region* (уменьшить выделение), `Shift-V` - *выделение строки*, но и стандартный `C-Space` продолжает работать.

[Вариант простого конфига в этом духе](https://gist.github.com/11111000000/a0d3500bd2613dfa7883b70c0e59959e)

Есть альтернативы [god-mode](https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode), например  [Modalka](https://github.com/mrkkrp/modalka).

Comment: @почему-то не хочет писать ваше имя . А как в Emacs у вас обстоит ситуация с переключением расскладок клавиатуры и клавишей ESC ?
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503988/vim-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: Для редкого переключения языков во время редактирования, не использую переключатель операцонной системы, но только функцию `toggle-input-method` - это чтобы при переключении не ломались сочетания и не писать хаки в конфиге. Можно замапить её на что-то удобное и сделать индикацию, спасибо что напомнили.

Answer (score 3):

Попробовал различные варианты.
IMHO стоит изучить клавиатурные комбинации установленные по умолчанию, т.к. и в справке и разной документации везде идут именно они. Как вариант можно назначать неиспользуюмые комбинации или клавиши под свои задачи.

Ну, а насчет переназначения стандартных клавиатурных сокращений, то как писал в комментариях @avp, просто потом нужно переназначить и ту функцию, комбинацию которой переназначили другой функции.
  Например, хотим функцию `undo` включать по `C-z`. Смотрим чем занято `C-z`, нажимаем `C-h k C-z`:
  `C-z runs the command suspend-frame, which is an interactive compiled`
   Назначаем этой функции другую комбинацию.

Answer (score 0):

CUA-mode
остальное как угодно.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?