# Кириллица в vim

Tags: vim, кириллица

Мне стало интересно научиться использовать текстовый редактор **Vim**. При обучении я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при переключении на русскую раскладку, сочетания клавиш перестают работать и приходится переключаться обратно на английскую раскладку. Что делать в этой ситуации?

Comment: возможный [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503988/178576)

Comment: Спасибо, да, но тут только половина ответа. У меня ещё вопрос про команду dw в кириллице.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Vim в Обычном \[Normal\] режиме всегда с английской раскладкой клавиатуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503988/vim-%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-normal-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim поддерживает кириллицу, но надо привыкнуть переключать язык не тем способом, которым вы это делаете в других приложениях.

Выполните следующие команды или включите их в файл `.vimrc`:

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
set iminsert=0
set imsearch=0
```

Теперь вы можете переключать раскладку по комбинации `Ctrl+^`. Вводите текст на любом языке, команды будут работать как обычно для любой раскладки.

Самое сложное отучится нажимать системную комбинацию для смены языка. Я до сих пор иногда делаю ошибки.

Comment: с кирилицей куча мороки, я, например, ее вообще по минимуму использую. Вернее даже сказать использую крайне редко - лучше привыкать писать хоть на ломанном, но на английском

Comment: Не согласен. Всё отлично работает. В виме можно даже курсор покрасить в зависимости от языка ввода. Очень удобно: английский - чёрный, русский - красный.